# Look for ways to enable printing from my C++/MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, printing

Since time immemorial I've been trying to avoid printing from my Windows-based applications due to the lack of native support for it. Whenever absolutely necessary I was resorting to dynamically making a simple HTML layout and then opening it in a web browser with a short Java Script in it to pop up a printing dialog for a user. Now I need to find something more substantial.

Let me explain. I have a project that deals with medical charts and it has to be able to print into those charts (at specific locations) as well as print on to a Letter/A4 size page in general. It also has to provide a preview of what is being printed in a paged-view environment.

In light of that I was wondering what is available from MFC/C++ environment (not C#) in regarding to printing?

PS. I was thinking to look into the RTF format but that seems like quite a daunting task, so I was also wondering, is there any libraries/already written code that can allow to compose/view/print RTFs? If not, what else is out there that can provide printing support like I explained above?

Answer (score 2):

"lack of native support"? It's been covered by Petzold since forever, and it's integrated straight into GDI. Compared to UNIX, it's a complete breeze. And MFC makes it even easier.

Anyway, [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edak6tf8.aspx) how you do print preview with MFC, and [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1est3b2.aspx) how you subsequently print. Lots of links from there, and it's all straightforward. Printers are just another Device Context on which you can draw.

Answer (score 1):

I always found it very convenient to generate PDF files from my MFC/C++ application, There are many libraries out there which enable easy creation of PDF files, preview functionality and so on (also open source). I'm using this (also handles RTF):

[PDF Library](http://www.idealsoftware.com/en/vpe/concept/pdf_library.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no support like you call a framework method with some parameters and the framework prints a document or the content of a window for you. You need to manually draw everything on the printing device context. So as already said, you might find it more convenient to use a PDF generator, but of course that depends on your application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [www.oxetta.com](http://www.oxetta.com) , it's a free report builder solution that easily integrates into a C/C++ application.